# Highcharts: Attach a click event to dataLabel when useHTML set to true

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a networkGraph in Highcharts and there's a click event attached to the "points", however I'd like to fire that event when an item within the `dataLabel` is clicked.

This fiddle is similar to what I have https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xsLnmd0u/, which Wojciech has been very helpful with. Notice that if you click the `dataLabel` nothing happens. But if you set `useHTML` to false then clicking the `dataLabel` does the same as clicking the marker.

In my version I have some `span`s inside the dataLabel that I want to fire the click event with, but it doesn't work at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can add events to nodes dataLabels using js `addEventListener` like that:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'networkgraph',
    marginTop: 50,
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var nodes = this.series[0].nodes;

        nodes.forEach(function(node) {
          node.dataLabel.div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            console.log('click')
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8uy4aq6z/